# How can a Windows program detect Python installations?

Tags: python, davinci-resolve

I am trying to determine how a given Windows application locates and loads the Python installation it's going to use.

Some context : I have **Python 3.12** installed on my system (for my own programming). But I also have a Windows application installed, named "DaVinci Resolve", which needs **Python 3.6** in order to offer a certain functionality.

Problem: That application keeps detecting and loading Python 3.12.

Please note that it succeeds in loading Python 3.12, which is a good thing because then I can run some commands to check `sys.path` and `platform.python_version()` . The issues only arise later, when I try to use that certain functionality I was mentionning (it's a scripting API. It requires Python 3.6). That API is the whole point of using that application, it's my end goal. Don't let it distract you, if you want the full story you can find it here : https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=168568&p=1009509#p1009509

I'm giving you the short version of my attempts:

- **If %PATH% *only* contains Python 3.6 then the application *still* loads Python 3.12** (I've verified by starting the application from a
  command prompt where I `echo %PATH%` before, and also do
  `print(sys.path)` from with the application after startup. Both show
  only python36)
- **If I "hide" the folder containing Python 3.12** (by renaming it temporarily) then the application says that Python is not installed on the system. If it was merely scanning the folders then it would still detect Python 3.6!

**Hence the question :
What are the standard-ish ways used by a Windows application to locate Python installations on the system?**

- PATH is out of the way, as demonstrated
- I'm not looking for completely custom (goofy) methods, only standard methods that I might not know but that experienced Python users might know.

Comment: Trying to use Python 3.6 at all is the "goofy" method - [that version reached End Of Life](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3615/) in 2021. `Don't let it distract you` but *that* is the actual problem. If you can't find an updated version of the application you'll have to manually install the last Python 3.6 version

Comment: As for making your program run with a different python version, you'll have to create a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) with the version you want and activate it before starting your application. Activating an environment modifies the path and environment variables to point to a specific Python version and packages

Comment: Also check [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not my fault if that application works only with an old Python. That being said : Never heard of Python virtual environments, I'll give it a try. And I'll research how they relate to the Python launcher (if they relate at all)

Comment: They do relate - they're a fundamental concept. The "launcher" is the `python.exe` included in the virtual environment itself. Without a virtual environment all Python projects on a machine would have to use the *same* module versions. Upgrading a module in one project would upgrade it for all other projects

Comment: I am utterly baffled. I ran the annoying application from the virtual environment I created from Python 3.6. I was absolutely sure it would work. And yet the application still loaded python 3.12 !

Comment: Did you start the application from the same terminal where you activated the environment? This [forum discussion](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=173991) complains that DaVinci Resolve 18.1 looks at PYTHONHOME to find Python. When you open a terminal or console and activate a venv, you're actually modifying PYTHONHOME, PYTHONPATH etc to point to the virtual environment's paths. Any application you start from inside that terminal/console will see the environment variables set by the `activate` script

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I'm running it from that same terminal/venv, which explains why I'm baffled by it not working. I've had testimonies of people managing to make it work as intended on Linux. But on Windows DaVInci Resolve consistently picks up on the wrong Python and the cause remains mysterious.

Comment: You can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what the application is doing to detect the Python version. You can use ProcMon to find out what registry settings or files the application is using to detect the Python executable